# How can I update contents on an HTML5 web application

Tags: database, storage, html

I'm going to write an HTML5 app based on contents.
I planning to store the contents into the local Database.
Now, how can I schedule the updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice html 5 presentation [here](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#web-storage).

here is an example from there:

```
// use localStorage for persistent storage
// use sessionStorage for per tab storage
saveButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  window.localStorage.setItem('value', area.value);
  window.localStorage.setItem('timestamp', (new Date()).getTime());
}, false);
textarea.value = window.localStorage.getItem('value');
```